# anaconda navigator the following packages will be modified solving package specifications Issue

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a problem about install package via Anaconda Navigator.
I tried to install geopandas but A lot of time has passed and the process could not be done.
I'm stuck in there. 
Here is the screenshot as shown below.

[image]

How can I fix it.

Comment: Try using Conda from the command line, it should give you more output.

Comment: I have the same problem and the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed it from Command Line in Conda. The solution is shown below.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

Comment: did you ever figure out why Anaconda Navigator install did not work?

Comment: @jrive I didn't try it in Anaconda Navigator after I solved it out via Command Line in Conda.